# Post uneditable values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view and a model (say Car). One field is editable in the form (the other info is only shown). When the view form get posted, I need all the info, not only the editable property. But all the other properties are null.

I used to create hidden fields to post the data, but when you have more hidden field than non-hidden ones, it's makes really dirty code.

Is there a way of posting all properties of a model without using hidden fields?

Comment: What makes you think hidden fields are not appropriated?

Comment: It seems your have to use ViewModel pattern and accept CarViewMode instance (which have only required/editable fields) instead of Car here. Than you can map your CarViewModel to Car object. More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvc3fundamentals_topic7.aspx

Comment: Passing the uneditable fields to the client and back is not the way to do it. it's inefficient (transferring all that data just to make your life easier) and a security risk (inquisitive user changes value you didn't expect changed). Far better to manage the merge on the server.

Comment: @SimonHalsey There is no security risk if the server-side is well coded: for instance, if you don't update an entity with all values that come from the client, but you have a service that only updates what's allowed to be updated (editable property by editable property), there's no problem.

Comment: @ken2k you are right, but I figured if we round-tripping all the data to save reloading it, chances are we won't check which fields we were saving.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a ViewModel with the editable fields only.
In the view just place the id for the model in database as a hidden field.

In your controller, get the model from database. Then do some check if you indeed can modify this item (someone could change the id in hidden field using Firebug for instance).

Then, just update the database model with the fields in your ViewModel... and save the model to database again.

If you use your CAR model in the view, someone could change more fields than you permitted... if you use CarViewModel, it is impossible as the model binder will just bind the properties of the viewmodel.

Comment: +1 for the "get model from DB by id, update only what's allowed, save to DB"

Comment: I too think this is the correct way... Use ViewModel with editable fields + model primary key,  and add `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)` to view, and update db using ViewModel...

Answer (score 2):

The data that is post in an html form is the content of the inputs. I don't think there is a problem with having hidden fields if you need this data on the post, it is what hidden fields are for.

That being said, if you really want to reduce the ammont of hidden fields, you could "serialize" all these info in one field and then "deserialize" it in the post. Or in a custom Model Binder.

But if you want the ModelBinder's magic that is out of the box in Asp.Net MVC, you have to use form fields.

Answer (score -1):

If you are apposed to having the information posted in hidden fields, another option would be to include them in the querystring.

Comment: Using the query string is probably even worse than using hidden fields. At least with hidden fields the user can't see what you're passing around